# Handle Gstreamer flow error without closing pipeline

Tags: c, gstreamer

i have a gstreamer application that creates a pipeline to acquire image from a camera, encode to h264 (using hardware encoder on rockchip SoC), parse h264 (h264parse) and push it to a custom plugin. The flow works fine most of the time but, it seems that sometimes, the encoder produces an invalid h264 NAL (i can't really debug that part) which cause the h264parse element to fails and return a flow error. When the error happens, i print the error message but don't stop or quit the pipeline. When doing so, the pipeline is stalled and the h264parse element stops getting buffers.

In most GStreamer examples, the error handling consists of stopping and exiting but in my case, I would prefer to recover from the error and keep the pipeline rolling. What is the correct way to do so? Would changing the pipeline state to play solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that the pipeline state is not affected by the error. It's just the parser that does not get new buffer after emitting an error. Changing the pipeline state to play does not solve the issue either.